# Can the NavigationTimingAPI be used on asynchronous calls?

Tags: javascript, navigation-timing-api, resource-timing-api

I'm currently implementing performance measuring functionality in our project which uses custom elements v1.

The [NavigationTimingAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) offers very detailed measuring on different navigation types (navigate, reload, browser back/forward):

[image]

Can the same (or similarly detailed) be made available for **asynchronous** calls as well? Or is there another API for that which I'm unaware of?

That is, when the page is fully loaded and some user interaction or event triggers a POST or GET on a server-located resource.

The only thing I found so far is setting measurepoints using [`performance.mark()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/mark).

Did I miss something crucial here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the obvious here.

Each `XMLHTTPRequest` with all the applicable details is automatically available as a `PerformanceResourceTiming` object in

```
performance
  .getElementsByType("resource")
  .filter(function(x) { 
    return x.initiatorType === "xmlhttprequest";
  });
```

I was looking into the `performance.timing` object only (actually the only thing not available via `performance.getElementsByType()`).

Answer (score 1):

You named *Navigation Timing* and found the *User Timing* with `performance.mark()` but missed the [*Resource Timing API*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resource_Timing_API/Using_the_Resource_Timing_API). All three is parts of the *Performance Timing API*.

*Navigation Timing* measures the homepage or app. *Resource Timing API* is similar but it’s provided for each individual asynchroniously loaded resource to get them compaired in relation to the navigation times.

Think about this: ***Asynchroniously loaded files has no DOM to run***! That means dom-properties is missing in resource timing. But the beginning part is same as in navigation timing:

[image]

How about *startTime* that is the most important property of Performance Timing API? Each asychronious call has their own! The *startTime* is `0` for document and `>0` ms for Javascript files and resources.

The *startTime* is the first recorded timestamp - an origin of measures. It marks the time when the browser first starts the process of loading the resource. In resource timing [*startTime* is same as *fetchStart* or *redirectStart* (if not zero)](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing-2/#dfn-starttime) when timing a resource.

Resources as CSS or images has neither dom or execution, but resources with `.js` extension executes Javascript, so there is a user timing possible with `performance.mark()` as you already found out.

> - ***Can the NavigationTimingAPI be used on asynchronous calls?***

Yes and No. Resource Timing get marks automatically that can be relative to Navigation Timing that make very useful comparisions. So yes - but no: Measuring index.html (navigation) and measuring asynchronious calls (resources) is not the same:
Change `performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")` to `performance.getEntriesByType("resource")`.